# How to solve error 'Trying to get property of non-object' in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

The following is the part of my code. But when I run that code, I am getting error "Trying to get property of non-object".

```
            $searchdate = Input::get('curdate');
            $teacherid = Auth::user()->id;
            $student = WysStudent::where('studcls',$id)->get();
            $clss = WysClass::where('clsteacher_id',$teacherid)->get();
            $attendence_tbl = WysAttendancename::where('cls_id',$id)->first();
            $wys_attendence_table = $attendence_tbl->attendance_name;
            $attendance = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)->where('adate','=',$searchdate)->get();
            if($attendance && $student){
                foreach ($attendance as $attendance) {
                    foreach ($student as $student) {
                        var_dump($student->id);
                    }
                }                
            }
```

How will I solve this problem??

```
$attendance = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)->where('adate','=',$searchdate)->get();
```

Comment: In which line of your code?

Comment: is this problem due to $attendance = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)->where('adate','=',$searchdate)->get();

Comment: when I try to do var_dump($student->id), i am getting error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue is here:

```
$student = WysStudent::where('studcls',$id)->get();
…
foreach ($student as $student) {
```

To fix it use `$studentS` variable for array of students and `$student` for loop iterator, like this:

```
$students = WysStudent::where('studcls',$id)->get();
…
foreach ($students as $student) {
```